# An unhandled exception occurred in angular using ng serve

Tags: angular

Hi I am Trying to Run an admin Panel With Angular but when I Want To Run the Project I get The following Error

```
**An unhandled exception occurred: error TS5058: The specified path does not exist: 'D:/tsconfig.json'.**
```

This Is My TsConfig Code

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@config/*": ["app/config/*"],
      "@core/*": ["app/modules/core/*"],
      "@menu/*": ["app/modules/menu/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["app/modules/shared/*"],
      "@user/*": ["app/modules/user/*"],
      "exceljs":[
        "node_modules/exceljs/dist/exceljs.min"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

what Should I do To fix The problem?

Comment: Do you run the command in your project folder?

Comment: @JoHTVS yes i do

Comment: As far as I can see, you are running `ng serve` in your disk `D`, not in your project - unless you have project  flatly in your `D`.

Comment: please share the content of your tsconfig.app.json

Answer (score 0):

If you have something similar in your tsconfig.app.json like this:

```
"extends": "/tsconfig.json",
```

then you should fix the path. Maybe:

```
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
```

Comment: You shared your tsconfig.json.  please share the content of your tsconfig.app.json to.  What is your start command?

Answer (score 0):

Inside Angular.json, Check the lint key is configured like below code.

Projects > architect

```
"lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer! To make it more helpful, could you please provide a bit more detail and lengthen your explanation? This will give a clearer understanding to both the asker and future visitors. Your contribution is valued!